# CSS transparency in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, symbology, vector, color

I have imported a very simple shapefile to my map in GEE. Since this layer represents boundaries (see picture below), I am trying to find a way for the outline colour to be solid black whilst rendering the fill colour transparent instead of white. Is there a way to do this? I don't want to make the whole layer transparent.

My code is very basic but is as follows:

```
var symbology = {color: 'black', fillColor: 'white'};
Map.addLayer(table2.style(symbology));
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where Earth Engine accepts a color name or hex code, you can use an eight-digit hex code where the last two digits are the alpha (opacity) value.

```js
var symbology = {color: 'black', fillColor: '#FFFFFF77'};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the undergiven code to ensure that only border is visible.

```
var styling = {color: 'black', fillColor: '#FFFFFF00'}

Map.layers().add(table2.style(styling))
```